Intermittent network connectivity
I have a Lenovo Thinkstation P710 that I recently decided to run linux directly from to host some Qemu workloads rather than using VmWare Esxi for better performance. More specifically, GNS3 for network simulations.
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
When I ping the server, it responds intermittently with no specific pattern.
I found out that pinging any destination FROM the server will fix this problem. as long as there is an active ping running ( I assume any kind of constant stream of traffic would do the trick), but as soon as I stop the ping things fall apart.
I disabled one of the NICs from the Bios thinking that it might be the fact that there are two NICs and maybe Ubuntu doesn't know how to handle them. Didn't make a different.
I installed ESXi again and setup a vm with another version of Ubuntu. It has the exact same problem! even running through ESXi, and when I lose ping on the Ubuntu VM the ESXi server constantly replies without a problem.
The other issue that might be related is that no matter what I do, it does not sync it's date and time with an NTP server.
I followed the below recommendations and only
sudo date -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z"

works.
What is the command to update time and date from internet
Thanks!
